# Deploying a Kubernetes cluster to Digital Ocean?

Tags: digital-ocean, kubernetes

It seems like get.k8s.io is the recommended way to deploy a Kubernetes cluster, but Digital Ocean isn't supported by this script.

Is there an alternate way to easily set up a cluster on Digital Ocean that I've missed?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-kubernetes ?

Comment: That guide mentions that it was developed with version 0.7, so I thought it was likely to be out of date. It'd be great if there was something like get.k8s.io which did all the work for the user.

Comment: My guess is that as k8s matures, there'll be more and more hosted support like Google Container Engine. (Disclaimer: I'm a Google employee.) I wouldn't like to say whether there's a simpler way of getting running on Digital Ocean at the moment, I'm afraid.

Comment: Understood, I'll use Google Container Engine to learn kubernetes then :)

Comment: I am working on a PR to provide some kubernetes love on coreos hosted at DigitalOcean. You can have a look at: https://github.com/looztra/coreos-k8s-demo/tree/update_052015 . For the moment, I still encounter some problems with the DNS (SkyDNS) service but kubernetes without DNS is alreay ok

Answer (score 3):

You can use `kubicorn` to create a fairly dope kubernetes cluster in Digital Ocean pretty easily. Here are the steps needed to do so:

```
// Install kubicorn
go get github.com/kris-nova/kubicorn

// Configure your auth
export DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN=***************************************** 

// Create your kubernetes profile from the default profile
kubicorn create mycluster --profile do

// Tweak your cluster as you like
kubicorn edit mycluster

// Apply your profile
kubicorn apply mycluster -v 4

// Use kubectl to access your cluster
kubectl get no
```

Note that `kubicorn` is vendored to be a library as well as a command line tool, so you should probably be able to also include this logic in a program if you'd like.

Source: https://www.nivenly.com/kubernetes-on-digital-ocean-with-encrypted-vpn-service-mesh/

Comment: Please take a few moments to improve your answer by *summarizing* the important information from the linked blog post here. Since we're building a library of information for the long term, we require all answers to be self-contained and include links [only for reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259)

Comment: I updated with a concrete example.. I hope that helps thanks!

Comment: How to add external ip on digital ocean?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Kubeadm. Today I have installed a Kubernet cluster on digital ocean using Kubeadm.

It seems Kubeadm is a google developed tool and going to be google's recommended way soon. Though, as of today it is in alpha state now.

The details are given here [Using kubeadm to Create a Cluster | Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/)

Comment: Kubeadm is currently in Beta and is not production ready. If you just wanna kick the tires with kubernetes it might be ok, but for more serious deployments I would suggest using something like kargo(ansible) or conjure-up or go with a service provider like GCE or AWS

Answer (score 2):

You can do it manually, or using Ansible. I would suggest that you take a look at this github repo https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/blob/master/contrib/inventory_builder/inventory.py

You can actually deploy a working, multi-node, TLS-secured, production ready k8s cluster just by following these simple steps:

1) Create one or more machines on your favourite cloud hosting provider

> You can use a Terraform script or do it by hand.

2) `git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/blob/master/contrib/inventory_builder/inventory.py`

3) touch ./kubespray/inventory/inventory.cfg

4) Edit the file you've just created and do something like:

```
[etcd]
<master-ip>

[kube-master]
<master-ip>

[kube-node]
<node1-ip>
<node2-ip>
<node3-ip>

[k8s-cluster:children]
kube-node
kube-master
```

> Look at the inventory example file for reference

5) install ansible on your machine via brew or apt-get e.g.

```
brew install ansible
```

6) run the ansible playbook

```
ansible-playbook -u root -b -i inventory/inventory.cfg cluster.yml
```

The user depends upon the Linux Distro you chose to deploy on the machines, but make sure that the use you select has root access.

Check out this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9q51JgbWu8&t=339s

Comment: I have problem to get external ip in digital ocean, maybe do you have some solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Tim Smart](https://github.com/tim-smart) put together some Digital Ocean Ansible playbooks [here](https://github.com/ARISEChurch/do-k8s-playbooks). I haven't tried them, but it looks like they have been updated to work with Kubernetes v1.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this a start point. I have used it too.

https://github.com/jiteshmohan/kubernetes-do

I got an old version of my current scripts to deploy my personal cluster to DO using terraform if you want to take a look.

https://github.com/cescoferraro/kubernetes-do

LOoks like Skippbox came up with a nice tool to deploy a single kubernetes instance on DO:

https://github.com/skippbox/kmachine